# How to restore small whiskey barrel?

Tags: wood, wood-repair, restoration

I was gifted a small barrel, maybe a half gallon (guessing) in volume, pictured below.

[image]

I let it sit for too long, I guess, and now there are gaps between all the staves. I read somewhere that you just have to soak it to get the slats to swell, so I tried that -- but the hole didn't seal up, and it still leaks. I've since let it dry out again.

Is there anything I can do to restore it and get it to seal again? I'm not that concerned with aesthetics, so I've considered trying to squeeze epoxy or wood glue into the gaps.

Failing that, I guess I could take all the hoops off, plane or sand the edges of each stave so they fit snugly, and put it back together. I have no idea how or where to find or make replacement hoops, though, as I assume the existing ones would be too small once I remove material from the staves.

So my question is:

1. Can it be repaired or restored without disassembling in a way where it'll still be suitable for aging some whiskey in it?
2. If I need to disassemble it to restore it, what materials or tools will I need, and what's a good place to get them?

Comment: I would suggest you get a hold of a Cooperage for advise. https://barrelbuilders.com/shop-services/

Comment: Knock the barrel bands lower. They're a fixed circumference so the lower they are seated the greater the squeezing force they apply. If this doesn't close up the gaps there's a chance that, as legit as this looks, this isn't actually a barrel but instead a BSO — barrel-shaped object.

Comment: That's a pretty cool little barrel. The question I have is: Did it ever seal up water-tight, or are you chasing something that never was? Was it originally full of whiskey?

Comment: Could you add more detail about your process for soaking it? Asking b/c I was given a 3.5gal bourbon barrel and had the same issue initially, but soaking it for _days_ fully submerged fixed it - my initial soak just wasn't thorough or long enough...

Comment: @greg Nickiloff it appeared to seal up tightly when Infirst soaked it - there were no obvious leaks, anyway. But I put a bottle of cheap whiskey in it, and when I checked a couple weeks later it was completely gone. Must have been a slow leak, since I hope I’d have smelled a puddle of whiskey in the corner of my living room! (C:

Comment: @AKA good point - I can give it another shot for longer. I only tried soaking it for a few hours this times around.

Comment: @Dathan your whiskey just got soaked into staves, if you haven't seen any leaks outside - it's water tight, just put more whiskey.

Comment: Dathan, in addition to fully soaking the barrel before you start an ageing experiment* (see more below) you pretty much want to fill the barrel... so you need to put in about a *gallon* of whiskey based on your estimate of the capacity, not just one bottle! Also note there is always some loss of ethanol to evaporation in spirits in barrels. * You're aware that for ageing to have any noticeable beneficial effect you're looking at the loooong term, right? Just one extra year won't cut it, it's possible/likely that you need to store it for a minimum of 5 additional years for this to be worth it.

Comment: @Dathan Did you question your housemates? Maybe it didn't evaporate or leak ;)

Comment: @Graphus Oh yeah, no worries there. If it'll seal, I'm happy to let it sit for years.

Answer (score 2):

Take it outside and fill with water. It will leak, so you will have to fill it up a few times. It would take a few days, just sprinkling some water will not work. If it still leaks after a 4-3 days a stave has to be replaced (could be rotten or a deep splinter). There's a way to fix a some leaks with a dry typha leave, but it's very improbable that you will find it and all the tools needed for this operation.

If soaking works, please be reminded that once it's completely dry it will leak again and that a few dry-soak cycles may damage the barrel up to the point of replacing many (or all) staves. In other words keep it full with water, whiskey or wine, make sure it's clean, almost sterile inside before putting anything or it will get spoiled.

If you will disassemble it - 99.9% you won't put it back. It requires a considerable skill (e.g. staves have a compound angle along a curved profile and it has to match perfectly with the adjacent one, repeat x number of staves), a lot of experience and physical strength and a set of tools you probably won't find around. Epoxy and glue works only if you want it as a decoration. But I think a good soak would fix your problem, because it doesn't look damaged from the photo.